# How to set autocomplete="off" in system.xml in magento?

Tags: magento2

I've just been given a requirement to add autocomplete="off" for the field in system.xml

```
<field id="primary_color" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Primary Color</label>
        <frontend_model>XXX\YYY\Block\Color</frontend_model>
</field>
```

Comment: Try this way https://mage2.pro/t/topic/125